# I need an explanation or an example of the following sentence

Tags: python, operators

The sentence is given below.
"An arithmetic expression is made up of constants ,variable ,a combination of both or a function call connected by arithmetic operator"

I need an elaboration and an example of the part where it says "a function call,connected by arithmetic operators

Comment: `spam = 2 + pow(3, 2)` in this case you on the right-hand side you have an arithmetic expression that is constant `2` and function call `pow(3, 2)`, connected by arithmetic operator `+`. Can you guess the value of `spam`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the following (simplified purely for demonstration) example:

```
def add_numbers(a, b):
    return a + b  # Returns an integer

result = 5 + add_numbers(3, 7)
print(result)
```

If you have a look at the `result = 5 + add_numbers(3, 7)`: this will be interpreted by Python as "run the function 'add_numbers', obtain the returned result and then add it to 5". So, once fully evaluated, that line effectively ends up as:

result = 5 + 10

in this example.

In other words, you can think of it as Python replacing the function call in your code with the returned value of that function, and then performing the addition on those two values.